# Problem downloading Maven dependencies in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, automation, dependencies

These errors have been throwing me off. I have the same exact setup as my coworker and he has no errors for our project in Intellij. Any ideas on how to fix these errors? I am trying to download Maven dependencies and I am just not having any luck. We spent a whole two days trying to fix this. I am new to the company and we need this project setup so I can get working. Many thanks in advance! Below are my errors I am receiving. The packages apparently do not exist and it is failing to download.

com.hp.lft:common:15.2.0

com.hp.lft:report:15.2.0

com.hp.lft:reportbuilder:15.2.0

com.hp.lft:sdk:15.2.0

com.hp.lft:unittesting:15.2.0

com.hp.lft:verifications:15.2.0

org.testng:jcommander:6.9.12

com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.3

Comment: Which errors? So I can't have an idea because I don't see anything useful... Furthermore why do your colleagues don't help? If it is that important start find a consultant and pay them for helping/fixing your issues...

Comment: Sorry I am unsure how to format on this site. Pretty new to it. My colleagues have been trying to help but they cant figure it out either. Just curious as to what the issue could be. with maven dependencies.

Comment: This will happen initially as you will not access from your IDE(specially in IntelliJ). Quick way to fix this is : get the JARS from your friend/coworker which are in .m2->repository->com->hp and place it in your .m2->repository->com->hp(if hp not there just copy paste it in com folder). this will resolve your issue(I guess, cz for me it is resolved)

Comment: So if you have "errors" , why dont post that errors here?

Answer (score 0):

Look for your desired dependencies in https://mvnrepository.com

If they do not exist, then you need to find a dependency that exists. Otherwise, try finding those dependencies online and download them as files to import them through IntelliJ.

---

**Example of a correct dependency**:

oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3